# Cannot Import name 'Layer'

Tags: tensorflow, keras, jupyter-notebook

I am having a problem with my code. I am running a Mask RCNN demo. I suspect I might not have installed the correct version of tensorflow or keras:

```
import os
import sys
import random
import math
import numpy as np
import skimage.io
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

## Root directory of the project

```
ROOT_DIR = os.path.abspath("../")

# Import Mask RCNN
sys.path.append(ROOT_DIR)  # To find local version of the library
from mrcnn import utils
import mrcnn.model as modellib
from mrcnn import visualize
# Import COCO config
sys.path.append(os.path.join(ROOT_DIR, "samples/coco/"))  # To find local version
import coco

%matplotlib inline 

# Directory to save logs and trained model
MODEL_DIR = os.path.join(ROOT_DIR, "logs")

# Local path to trained weights file
COCO_MODEL_PATH = os.path.join(ROOT_DIR, "mask_rcnn_coco.h5")
# Download COCO trained weights from Releases if needed
if not os.path.exists(COCO_MODEL_PATH):
    utils.download_trained_weights(COCO_MODEL_PATH)

# Directory of images to run detection on
IMAGE_DIR = os.path.join(ROOT_DIR, "images")
```

It gives me an error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-12-ebe7095df7bb> in <module>
     13 # Import Mask RCNN
     14 sys.path.append(ROOT_DIR)  # To find local version of the library
---> 15 from mrcnn import utils
     16 import mrcnn.model as modellib
     17 from mrcnn import visualize

~\Mask_RCNN\mrcnn\utils.py in <module>
     14 import random
     15 import numpy as np
---> 16 import tensorflow as tf
     17 import scipy
     18 import skimage.color

~\.conda\envs\MaskRCNN\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py in <module>
     39 import sys as _sys
     40 
---> 41 from tensorflow.python.tools import module_util as _module_util
     42 from tensorflow.python.util.lazy_loader import LazyLoader as _LazyLoader
     43 

~\.conda\envs\MaskRCNN\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py in <module>
     47 from tensorflow.python import distribute
     48 # from tensorflow.python import keras
---> 49 from tensorflow.python.feature_column import feature_column_lib as feature_column
     50 # from tensorflow.python.layers import layers
     51 from tensorflow.python.module import module

~\.conda\envs\MaskRCNN\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\feature_column\feature_column_lib.py in <module>
     20 
     21 # pylint: disable=unused-import,line-too-long,wildcard-import,g-bad-import-order
---> 22 from tensorflow.python.feature_column.feature_column import *
     23 from tensorflow.python.feature_column.feature_column_v2 import *
     24 from tensorflow.python.feature_column.sequence_feature_column import *

~\.conda\envs\MaskRCNN\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\feature_column\feature_column.py in <module>
    145 from tensorflow.python.framework import sparse_tensor as sparse_tensor_lib
    146 from tensorflow.python.framework import tensor_shape
--> 147 from tensorflow.python.layers import base
    148 from tensorflow.python.ops import array_ops
    149 from tensorflow.python.ops import check_ops

~\.conda\envs\MaskRCNN\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\layers\base.py in <module>
     18 from __future__ import print_function
     19 
---> 20 from tensorflow.python.keras.legacy_tf_layers import base
     21 
     22 InputSpec = base.InputSpec

~\.conda\envs\MaskRCNN\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\__init__.py in <module>
     23 
     24 # See b/110718070#comment18 for more details about this import.
---> 25 from tensorflow.python.keras import models
     26 
     27 from tensorflow.python.keras.engine.input_layer import Input

~\.conda\envs\MaskRCNN\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\models\__init__.py in <module>
     19 from __future__ import print_function
     20 
---> 21 from tensorflow.python.keras._impl.keras.models import load_model
     22 from tensorflow.python.keras._impl.keras.models import Model
     23 from tensorflow.python.keras._impl.keras.models import model_from_config

~\.conda\envs\MaskRCNN\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\_impl\keras\__init__.py in <module>
     19 from __future__ import print_function
     20 
---> 21 from tensorflow.python.keras._impl.keras import activations
     22 from tensorflow.python.keras._impl.keras import applications
     23 from tensorflow.python.keras._impl.keras import backend

~\.conda\envs\MaskRCNN\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\_impl\keras\activations.py in <module>
     23 from tensorflow.python.keras._impl.keras import backend as K
     24 from tensorflow.python.keras._impl.keras.utils.generic_utils import deserialize_keras_object
---> 25 from tensorflow.python.layers.base import Layer
     26 from tensorflow.python.platform import tf_logging as logging
     27 

ImportError: cannot import name 'Layer'
```

I have installed TensorFlow and keras. I am not entirely sure why there is an error.
How can I debug this,please?

Comment: Could you upgrade the tensorflow using `pip install --upgrade tensorflow` and let us know if the issue still persists? Also install mrcnn module `!pip install mrcnn`.

Answer (score 0):

This is the issue with your tensorflow. I think there is something wrong with your tensorflow installation, otherwise you should try tensorflow forum